# Tensorflow-GPU 2.10 does not detect my gpu

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow-GPU 2.10 does not detect my gpu.
I tried anything and i didn't work.

**tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')** Returns an empty list but **tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support()** Returns True.

Comment: Windows 10, Python 3.10.9 and TensorflowGPU 2.10.0 With Conda

Comment: Please check the [Hardware and Software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) to install TensorFlow with GPU setup. Please install all the required software (Nividia GPU driver, CUDA and cuDNN) and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the same link to enable GPU support in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please install all the required software(Nividia GPU driver, CUDA and cuDNN) and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in the below link to enable GPU support in your system.

[Software and Hardware Requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35532069)